# Select rows based on 2 columns

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I am not the greatest at SQL and I am trying to achieve the following:

I have a table with columns like so:

```
id | cup_type | cup_id | name
```

I have a ton of records in the database which will have the same `cup_id` but different `cup_types`

I would really like to select records that have the same `cup_id` but different `cup_types`

```
id | cup_type | cup_id | name
1  | TypeOne  | 12     | NameOne
2  | TypeTwo  | 12     | NameTwo
3  | TypeOne  | 13     | NameThree
4  | TypeTwo  | 13     | NameFour
5  | TypeOne  | 14     | NameFive
6  | TypeOne  | 14     | NameSix
```

When I run the said query it would being me back the following:

```
id | cup_type | cup_id | name
1  | TypeOne  | 12     | NameOne
2  | TypeTwo  | 12     | NameTwo
3  | TypeOne  | 13     | NameThree
4  | TypeTwo  | 13     | NameFour
```

I hope I have explained this ok and let me know if more clarity is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query would do the trick

```
select * from
yourtable a
join (select cup_id, count(distinct cup_type) nbType
        from yourTable
        group by cup_id) b using(cup_id)
where b.nbType >= 2;
```

- Get a result set from your table where you count the distinct `cup_type`.
- Group that result set by `cup_id`.
- Keep the `cup_id` so we can join on the same table, using that id.
- Return only those where the count of distinct types was at least two.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

select a.id, b.id ....... from t1 as a, t2 as b where a.cup_id=b.cup_id and a.cup_type !=b.cup_type